# Square root equation problem $2\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x+7}=0$

Tags: quadratics

I was solving some equations and got to this one:

$$2\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x+7}=0$$

I tried square the equation, but it seems that it only complicates the process.

Comment: Could give the original equations?

Comment: $x=2$ works... Worth noticing the easy solutions first, helps make the process concrete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Writing your equation in the form

$$2\sqrt{2x}=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+7}$$ and squaring gives

$$8x=x-1+x+7+2\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+7}$$
Can you finish?
Simplifying and squaring once more we get
$$9(x-1)^2=(x-1)(x+7)$$

Comment: worth noting, for the case $x > 1,$ your final equation becomes 9 = Mobius transformation(x), and inverting Mobius transformations is a surprisingly easy technique, worth learning even for beginners

Comment: Do you know any example of inverting with mobius transformation, it seems that I can't find anything like that